# Uint8Array.map(...) unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript

I tried to call .map on Uint8Array and got a surprise.

```js
const tt = new Uint8Array(1);
tt[0] = 0xFF;

const ttt = tt.map(x => x.toString(2));

console.log(ttt[0]);
console.log(tt[0].toString(2));
```

I expected both output to be '11111111', but first console.log prints the number 199. Why?

Comment: As `ttt` is an `Uint8Array` too, it will not contain a string `"11111111"` for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because [`Uint8Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/map) returns a `Uint8Array`. All the strings you return, get parsed as uint8s again ... and thus you get 199 (`11111111 & (2 ** 8 - 1)`).

You might wanna do:

```
 Array.from(tt).map(x => x.toString(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending my comment, As ttt is an Uint8Array too, it will not contain a string "11111111" for sure:

You get 199, because the string `"11111111"` is evaluated as number 11111111, which is `A98AC7` in hexadecimal, so casting to a byte takes `C7`, which is 199.